# Why printf can mask the race-condition whereas syslog doesn't?

Tags: c++, c, linux, syslog

I understand that printf can mask the race-condition in the code. However, I don't understand why syslog cannot mask it. People say that syslog resembles close to the release build. We have three build variants - debug ( serial debugging + syslog enabled), production ( syslog enabled), and release build ( no serial debugging and no syslog enabled). People say try production- that is enable syslog only to debug the issue. I couldn't understand why syslog will not mask the race-condition. Can somebody please explain?

Comment: Can you provide an example or context?  ie.  Can you provide an example where `printf` serialized things as you expect, but `syslog` did not?  Without some additional details (especially code examples), your question is too vague.

Answer (score 2):

The standard stdio functions, such as printf, perform locking to be thread-safe, so multi-threaded code that contains calls to printf can be to some extent serialized. This can change the behavior of code with race conditions. (You can look at the man page for "unlocked_stdio" for non-locking versions of some of the stdio functions. Using one or the other can make for surprisingly large performance differences in some cases.)

I'm less familiar with syslog. As far as I know, *some* versions of syslog don't do any locking, aren't thread-safe, and don't cause the same serialization, but the Linux syslog implementation *is* thread-safe, and should cause similar (but probably not exactly the same) serialization as printf.

So according to my understanding, "people" are wrong.

Comment: +1 and retracting my answer, because I was unaware that stdio functions performed locking.  I learned something new today.